# Relational Database Design - Primary Key Field

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-database

I've got this relation Justifications (stores the documents of justification for the absence) and has these attributes ID, Type and Date.
The problem is there are many types of justification documents medical, marriage, death... (7 types total) every document has its own ID, code or serial number which is unique but the size and contents (character, symbols, numbers) differ in each type.
Should I use the ID, code or serial number of the document as a primary key, using a field with the size of the longest ID and a VarChar (SQLServer) as a type? Or shouldn't I and Why? Any alternatives?

Thanks!!

Comment: "justification for the absence" - Is "laid low by a fish" one of them? Also, with the death one, how does the recipient fill it in? "Reason for absense" -  Death!  lol

Comment: ^^ u got me all wrong, I mean when someone close to you dies, you take 3 days off, and the justification ID will be the death certificate number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how much data your database will be holding. A couple fields of this type of mix will not be so bad, but a couple thousand and things will get complicated. I would suggest breaking it out, since you know each form, into separate tables. Where you have a table for each of the possible 7 types and a Justification which holds a foreign key to the relevant justification document.

```
example:

Justification
-------
JustificationId
DocumentId



Document (linking table)
-------
DocumentId
MedicalId
DeathId
etc.

Medical
-------
MedicalId
Date
Reason
DoctorSigning
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what is know in ER modeling as "category" (aka. "subtype", "subclass", "inheritance").

E.g. search for "Subtype Relationship" in the [ERwin Methods Guide](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/e002961e.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

1. The recommendation for a primary key is:

   a) An integer for fast lookup and easy storage can go to 4billion rows if you use unsigned

   b) Should have no business meaning, so that it is not affected when business rules changes
2. So do not use the ID or code or serial number as your primary key, as they will slow down your database.
3. However if those columns have unique values, then you may need a unique key constraint to enforce that.